# Get Linux Process List and state using C++

Tags: c++

I have a pet project where I am trying to develop a small antivirus program for Linux. I have already designed the mathematical model and the heuristic approach that I plan on using yet now I am struggling when trying to fingerprint the host machine. In order to achieve that, I need to list all the processes and their state and output them to a text file. I did try to accomplish that via scanning the proc folder recursively yet I was wondering if there is a better way to do this. I am aware of the fact that processes with a short lifespan will slip by when doing it this way so I am trying to find the most elegant and simple solution for this in C++. Up to date answers encouraged (no snippets from 2009 please :P).

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "fingerprint the host machine"?

Comment: Create a snapshot of all running processes :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture short-lived processes, you might want to look at the Audit subsystem or perf, and see if those might be able to record the details you want.